# Table array data with subtable

Tags: php, html, arrays, mysqli, html-table

About array elements with table using Php and Mysql, I have issue about this so the objective is the header show subtable by date. In theory show two arrays for table. Can you help me?

Image sample:

[image]

I paste the code PHP with Mysql.

```
echo "<table class='tbmapa' width='300px' align='center'>";
echo "<col width='30%'><col width='60%'>";
$query = "SELECT fecdate FROM incidents";
$result = $conn->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<thead><tr>";
    echo "<th>DAY N° 01</th>";
    echo "<th id='data'>".$row['fecdate']."</th>";
    echo "</thead></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    $i=0;
    $conn->next_result();
    $query2 = "SELECT secc, time, desc, obs FROM incidents WHERE fecdate = '$_GET['data']'";
    echo "<table class='tbmapa' width='300px' align='center'>";
    echo "<col width='10%'><col width='10%'><col width='40%'><col width='30%'><col width='5%'><col width='5%'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>SEC</th>";
    echo "<th>TIME</th>";
    echo "<th>DESCRIPTION</th>";
    echo "<th>OBS</th>";
    echo "<th>EDIT</th>";
    echo "<th>SEND</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    $result1 = $conn->query($query2);
    while($rowdb = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$rowdb['secc']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$rowdb['time']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$rowdb['desc']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$rowdb['obs']."</td>";
        echo "<td>EDIT</td>";
        echo "<td>SEND</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    $x++;
}
$result->close();
```

thank

Comment: This is more of a "how to program" than "help with php" but... I'd gather your entire dataset.  Loop through it, and build an associative array using the date as your keys, and for the values make that an array of the other bits of data.  Then loop through with a `foreach $arr as $k=>$v` and for each $k (your date, associative array index) display the sub-header and then loop through the $v (the records for that day)

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are asking.  You have shown the intended result and the code, but you neither show what you get with that code, nor explain what explicit problem you are having.  People will be much more likely to help you out if you make those things clear and **fast** to understand.